# Passing HTML string at data

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a custom plugin. Its propitiatory so released resources are very minimum. The JS is something like this. Most of it makes sense to me.

```
Invodo.Widget.add({
    type:"cta", 
    podId:"HX9FM0DO",
    parentDomId:"cta_container6",
    widgetId:"cta6",
    data:"kerastase/images/Cat Banners/Category_Content_Slot_Images/play.png?$staticlink$"
});
```

This is how I am adding the div like this

```
Invodo.Widget.add({podId:"119OKII2", widgetId:"player3", mode:"overlay", type:"inplayer", listensTo:"cta3"});
```

and the div in the dom lives like this

```
<div id="cta_container6"></div>
```

Now the plugin is just appending an image to this div. But what If I want to just style the div and not append an image.

Am I getting the JavaScript fundamentally wrong or is it plugin specific?

Comment: What do you expect $staticlink$ to be. Is it just a constant or a variable?

Comment: Show us how are you passing the div?

Comment: well right now its relative url for the image. I can use any absolute url for any random image from google image or what ever, it doesnt matter. But I am trying to avoid using the image

Comment: Invodo.Widget.add({podId:"119OKII2", widgetId:"player6", mode:"overlay", type:"inplayer", listensTo:"cta6"});

and I am inserting a div in the dom like this 
<div id="cta_container6"></div>

Comment: No problem in all you have told so far. Could you add more code, if you wish me to look at.

Comment: just updated the question little bit more actually. Here is the link to the site. http://dev31.us.loreal.demandware.net/on/demandware.store/Sites-kerastase-Site/default/Search-Show?cgid=kerastase-regimen

I am trying to do this at the bottom of the page where I have the carousel. The top part play images are cool. I am not worried about that.

Comment: This widget plays video on click of the triangle image. You wish to remove the image and style the div yourself and may be handle the click event yourself. Pls confirm my understanding. Who is handling video playback? I have not seen any code for that in your examples aboe.

Comment: correct. All I want is to remove the image and style the div myself. This is a framework which is providing us the video. I can provide you with little bit of documentation what I have. 
http://demos.invodo.com/public/multipleOvp40.html